# how to make asp.net text box and dropdown flat style in css?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have asp.net textbox and dropdown list. trying to make flat model or fancy style. Please help me to figure out with some example and samples

```
.RegText
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 11.5pt;
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;  

}
.RegDropdown
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 11.5pt;
    height:35px;
    width:250px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;  
}
<td>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCostcenter" runat="server" CssClass="RegDropdown" 
       AutoPostBack="true" InitialValue="Select One"></asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td >
             <asp:Label ID="lbInitiative" runat="server" CssClass="RegLabel" Text="Initiative # :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtInitiative" runat="server" CssClass="RegText" ></asp:TextBox>
           </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@James123, I use this style on textboxes, it could help you:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea
{
  outline:none;
  border:solid 1px #BBB;
  padding:3px;
  font-size:20px;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, textarea:focus
{
  border:solid 1px #888;
}
```

And here is a page with good hints about fancy text and textbox: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa051607.htm

Answer (score 1):

Just use `border: 0;` for `input type=text` and `select`

```
input[type=text], select {
   border: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck6cR/1/)

Comment: textbox is fine , but dropdown arrowdown is not flat.

Comment: can you guys share any fancy style sample websites with css

Comment: @James123 check this out http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some more info ... you may want to use outline:0; as well to remove those "extra borders" (usually yellow in google chrome)